# Xamarin.Firebase.Crashlytics 118.0.1

Tags: firebase, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am working on adding Crashlytics to my app.

**This is the nuget package**
on my Android project

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Firebase.Crashlytics/118.0.1

**I put this in my strings.xml**

```
<string name="com.google.firebase.crashlytics.mapping_file_id">1.0</string>
```

The app loads great! but when I throw an exception I get no data in the console.

When I log into firebase and look at Crashytics it acts like I have not enabled it. In the instructions it says I need to enable it but I don't see an enable button.

What am I missing ?

[image]

Comment: did you follow the docs here?  https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=ios#enable-in-console

Comment: You need to do some initialization, more than just putting that string in your XML. See also here: https://medium.com/@hakimgulamali88/firebase-crashlytics-with-xamarin-5421089bb561

Comment: @Jason Something similar with Xamarin

Comment: @GeraldVersluis even for the version I have included ? I can't find those methods.

Comment: the docs for enabling Crashlytics in the console are the same for every platform

Comment: Thats actually not true. Xamarin is different. It follows a similar process but there is something missing in the Xamarin docs. Its ok if you don't have the answer Xamarin is not supported through firebase but through xamarin / Microsoft and there is not alot of documentation.

Comment: Have you looked at the sample app that Xamarin has: https://github.com/xamarin/GooglePlayServicesComponents/tree/main/samples/com.google.firebase/firebase-crash

Comment: Actually I have it does not complie and it uses Xamarin.Firebase.Crash which is werid